# rmi java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: RMIServerImpl_Stub

Tags: rmi

when i start rmiserver implementation class it displays this error message

```
Remote exception: java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server t
hread; nested exception is:
        java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested excep
tion is:
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: RMIServerImpl_Stub
```

commands ran

start rmiregistry

start java  -Djava.security.policy=policyfile RMIServerImpl

what can i do to resolve this. Please help

This is my rmi server code

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;
import java.rmi.registry.*;
```

public class RMIServerImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject
        implements RMIServer {

```
RMIServerImpl() throws RemoteException {


    super();
}


public static void main(String args[]) {


    try {
        System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());

        RMIServerImpl Server = new RMIServerImpl();


        Naming.rebind("SAMPLE-SERVER", Server);

        System.out.println("Server waiting.....");
    } catch (java.net.MalformedURLException mue) {
        System.out.println("Malformed URL: " + mue.toString());
    } catch (RemoteException re) {
        System.out.println("Remote exception: " + re.toString());
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you didn't run the rmic compiler to generate stubs and skeletons.

It's been so long since I've done raw RMI by hand that I don't know if that step is still required.  But it was the last time I did RMI.

If you did run rmic, then I'd guess that you didn't package the stub and skeleton properly with the server and client sides.  If you can find those .class files, check your packaging and deployment.

Comment: i ran rmic the stub class is there. there are no package statements in my java code. what can i do ?